# Render Error when coding project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

For a class project, I need to modify some basic pieces of a java android project. However, I cannot view any of the visual features of the app, as my activity_main.xml is showing a render error issue.

My build version is
*Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 1
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7621141, built on August 7, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7281165 x86_64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 11.4*

The error I am getting is here:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.lambda$createViewFromCustomInflater$0(BridgeInflater.java:259)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromCustomInflater(BridgeInflater.java:285)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.onCreateView(BridgeInflater.java:122)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:928)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:948)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1002)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:309)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:959)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1121)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1124)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1095)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1082)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:680)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:499)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:353)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:714)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$7(RenderTask.java:870)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.base/java.lang.StringLatin1.charAt(StringLatin1.java:47)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:693)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:1027)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getType(BridgeTypedArray.java:812)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.getValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:781)
    at android.content.res.BridgeTypedArray.peekValue(BridgeTypedArray.java:850)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:5951)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:996)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:87)
    at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:83)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:93)
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:88)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createEditText(AppCompatViewInflater.java:209)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:127)
    ... 31 more
```

I also have a string index out of range -1 error, and I am not sure where this stems from.

Here is the code for activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="18dp"
        android:background="#37009688"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="18dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="18dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="18dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/userMsgTV"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:text="@string/default_msg"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
            android:textColor="#009688"
            android:textSize="32sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/userInputET"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:autofillHints=""
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:hint="@string/write_msg_hint"
            android:inputType="text" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/showBtn"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:background="#E91E63"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
            android:onClick="showTextMessage"
            android:text="show text"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="left" />
        <!-- TODO 04. Set a new width value (120dp) for the button with the id "showBtn" -->
        <!-- TODO 05. Add a new property to the "showBtn" to align the text within to the left side of the button -->
        <!-- TODO 08. Add a new button with the id "cleanBtn" to the layout with the same properties of the show button (showBtn) -->
        <!-- TODO 09. Link the "cleanBtn" to the "cleanTextField" method so whenever the user taps the button the text field gets cleaned -->

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to SOF, can you add code part too?

Comment: @SaurabhDhage I have added the code the activity_main